# When did Java Restlet framework start supporting HTTPS through HTTP proxies?

Tags: java, restlet, http-proxy

I have become responsible for maintaining webapp that is running in Tomcat 8.0.33 with Java 8 that makes some outbound HTTPS restlet connections to another service (i.e. the webapp is a restlet client).

The webapp is using Restlet 2.0.11. (Which I realize is old, but for now, anyways, I am required to play the hand I've been dealt).

I have been asked to get the webapp to work when it is behind an HTTP proxy.  As an ugly quick and dirty test I simply set the JVM-wide proxy properties (`http.proxyHost`, `https.proxyHost`, etc.) to point to the proxy.

I can see traffic going to the proxy but the requests appear malformed, the proxy's response is that the requests are invalid, and the restlet client is throwing exceptions:

```
2016-05-02 19:47:23,643 org.restlet WARN  [Restlet-279974262]: Exception while writing the message headers.
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.writeMessageHead(Connection.java:907) [org.restlet-2.0.11.jar:na]
        at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.writeMessageHead(Connection.java:921) [org.restlet-2.0.11.jar:na]
        at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.writeMessage(Connection.java:796) [org.restlet-2.0.11.jar:na]
        at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.ClientConnection.writeMessage(ClientConnection.java:314) [org.restlet-2.0.11.jar:na]
        at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.writeMessages(Connection.java:954) [org.restlet-2.0.11.jar:na]
        at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Controller$1.run(Controller.java:81) [org.restlet-2.0.11.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

Before I go farther into trying to debug this I would like to know when the Restlet framework officially started supporting HTTPS requests through an HTTP proxy?  I'd like to know the answer for the internal client and for the Apache HttpClient client options.

I've done some searching in the bug database and have found a couple of potentially relevant issues, but with 2.0.11 being something like 4 years old and the migration of the bug database from wherever it was to github in the interim, when I see some stuff marked as "Unplanned" I'm not sure exactly what that means.

So when did the HTTP proxy support come in?

Comment: The commit that added support for `http.proxyHost` seems to be [this one](https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/commit/c8f4df35cf1222ad0e42ab6590330ad094831ec8) from 2010

Comment: Thanks.  But the problem isn't honoring the settings.  It is clearly honoring the settings since I'm seeing traffic go to the proxy.  And because HTTP requests from Restlet work fine through the proxy.

The problem is that Restlet isn't handling HTTPS through the proxy.

Comment: Did you solved your problem ? I have a webapp using restlet 2.2 and I'm looking for how using proxy settings (https). But it seems it's not possible ?